# How do I set a custom page template for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes

I need to set a custom template for a custom post type with standard wordpress functionality like this: [Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

I found these: [1 - custom post template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) , 2 - single post template , but its not working for a custom post type and this works only for built-in wordpress posts.

Comment: You can add custom post type support to the first plugin you listed, it's covered in the [other notes section](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/other_notes/). Very well written plugin to, should address your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the same problem a few months back. After several different ways I finally found a way that worked. Try adding this to your themes functions.php file *(be sure to replace both instances of portfolio to match the actual names you use)*:

```
<?php
add_action("template_redirect", 'your_cust_pt_redir');
function your_cust_pt_redir() {
   global $wp;
   global $wp_query;
   if ($wp->query_vars["post_type"] == "portfolio") { // Change Portfolio to your Post Type
      if (have_posts())   {
         include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/portfolio.php'); // The Custom Template
         die();
      } else {
         $wp_query->is_404 = true;
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for interest , you may point me to the right way , but i think is it better than to use your code or patch that plugins ? that i tell you in above when i want to use this codes several number in a big site that need to best performance